# Spring MVC dynamically configured getting 404 but works with MockMVC

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I have the following controller (notice how it's configured):

```
@Controller
public class MyController {
  @Autowired
  private RequestMappingHandlerMapping requestMappingHandlerMapping;

  @PostConstruct
  private void createRequestMapping() throws Exception {

    RequestMappingInfo commandExecutionRequestMappingInfo = 
    RequestMappingInfo
        .paths(endpointUri)
        .methods(RequestMethod.POST)
        .consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
        .produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
        .build();

    requestMappingHandlerMapping
        .registerMapping(commandExecutionRequestMappingInfo, this,
        MyController.class.getDeclaredMethod("execute", String.class));


    RequestMappingInfo getAvailableCommandsRequestMappingInfo =
       RequestMappingInfo
        .paths(endpointUri)
        .methods(RequestMethod.GET)
        .build();

     requestMappingHandlerMapping
        .registerMapping(getAvailableCommandsRequestMappingInfo, this,
       MyController.class
         .getDeclaredMethod("getAvailableCommands", Model.class));
  }

  @ResponseBody
  private String execute(@RequestBody String command) {
    ...
  }

  private String getAvailableCommands(Model model) {
    model.addAttribute("docs", handlerDocs);
    return "docs";
  }
```

There is a `docs.html` page which sits in `main/resources/templates/docs.html`.

When I run a test with MockMvc, it see the output of that page:

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan
@EnableAutoConfiguration
public class ApplicationConfig {
}
```

Here is the test class:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(classes = ApplicationConfig.class)
@AutoConfigureMockMvc
public class SpringRestCommanderTest {

  @Autowired
  private MockMvc mvc;

  @Test
  public void testGetAvailableCommands() throws Exception {
    mvc.perform(get("/execute")).andDo(print());
  }
}
```

However, when I run this same thing in a real app, it gives me a 404 for the GET request when I try it in the browser.

What's strange is that the SAME `/execute` works when issue a POST request to it. As you can see above, the dynamic mapping is very similar between POST and GET.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Well, besides that I would never do this in a production Code (reflection etc.) what is the value of `endpointUri`?

Comment: The value of `endpointUri` is `/execute`. Any idea/example of how to get this done?